# Convert base64 string to image at server side in java

Tags: java, image-processing, base64

I have base64 String which I want to convert back to image irrespective of image format at server side. I tried it by using following code, image is getting created but when I am trying to preview it, showing error could not load image.

```
public void convertStringToImage(String base64) {
        try {
            byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(base64);

            FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("./src/main/resources/demo.jpg");
            imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
            imageOutFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "ImageStoreManager::convertStringToImage()" + e);
        }
    }


    public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
        return Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
    }
```

what should I do so that my image will look properly?

Comment: Well have you looked at the file that's been created? How long is it compared with the base64? How have you verified that the base64 is correct to start with?

Comment: Your code should do the trick. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure your image is a jpg, not a gif, a png or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I can suggest however some more debugging steps for you.

1. Encode your file manually using, for example, this [webpage](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)
2. Compare if `String base64` contains exact same content like you've got seen on the page. // if something wrong here, your request is corrupted, maybe some encoding issues on the frontend side?
3. See file content created under `./src/main/resources/demo.jpg` and compare content (size, binary comparison) // if something wrong here you will know that actually save operation is broken

Remarks:

- Did you try to do `.flush()` before close?
- Your code in current form might cause resource leakage, have a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
    return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString.getBytes());
}
```